# Expand link (a) across image and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, hover

I am using a WordPress plugin which creates the following output:

```
<li>
  <a href="/permalink1/" class="wp_rp_thumbnail"><img src="/media/image-thumbnail.png"/></a>
  <a href="/permalink1/" class="wp_rp_title">Post Title</a>
</li>
```

I applied an `a:hover` style for both the image and the text. But of course they are triggered separate of each other, as there are two links being generated. I would like to have them triggered both on hover (in my case: image border color changes **and** text color changes - no matter which of the two elements are being hovered).

Of course I could fiddle into the plugin source and change how it is built there, but due to update-ability I thought it would be cleaner to change it with a few lines of jQuery. Unfortunately I don't know how to approach this and would be thankful for ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the hover on the li

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/SCZ4n/)**

```
li:hover img
{
    border: 2px solid green;
}
li:hover a
{
    color: orange;
}
```

Comment: D'oh. Yes, that's definitely the cleanest solution. Should have thought of that myself - thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you could use the hover function.
Something like this

```
$('.wp_rp_thumbnail, .wp_rp_title').hover(function(){
    $('.wp_rp_thumbnail img').css({"border":"1px solid #fff"});
    $('.wp_rp_title').css({"color":"#fff"});
});
```